# What does the direction of the compass in A Dark Room mean?

Tags: a-dark-room

Whenever I purchase a compass to unlock The Dusty Path, it always points a certain direction. What does that direction mean? Is it significant? Does the compass always point toward a certain location or does it just point to a location with a large number of places to explore?

Comment: How would you feel about editing out your specific guess about the location in case that's a spoiler for some people? I'm happy to do the editing if you like.

Comment: I edited them out, just in case. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the compass is pointing toward an important location, but the answer is a spoiler if you haven't yet beaten the game.

> [According to the author](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/issues/353#issuecomment-98546950) the compass always points towards the spaceship

Comment: I'm confused how that's a spoiler if the author already appears to be on track with what it is. Also, I don't think spoiler text should be used, if the rest of the body can not stand alone, without it. "Important location" does answer the question, I just don't think it answers the question well.

Comment: He just doesn't want to spoil it for others. OP was wondering if the direction was arbitrary. Now he can choose if he wants to know.

Comment: @Timelord64 My intent is exactly as Tkdestroyer2 explains. I agree it's a bit strange if the original question contains a possible spoiler as part of the guess. I'll ask the author.

Comment: I've beaten the game twice, and was wondering for next time what the compass represented. Although, in my experience, the compass doesn't point anywhere in particular, and the location which the creator says it points to doesn't align with where I've found the location previously. Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: @Rick_Roll I believe the thing it points to changes places from game to game - sometimes it might be on the east, other times the south, etc. Is that what you mean, or something else? Also, the location might not be exact - if it's pointing very close to SouthSouthSouthWest, maybe it will read West? Perhaps we could look at the code and see.

Comment: Thanks! How could we examine the code? Is it on github?